# AWS Lambda Authorizer returns "BadRequestException"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm using an AWS Lambda to authorize a GraphQL query, I want to use the authorization token to get the client information from Cognito, and use the sub in the user attributes to check if the user purchased a phone in my Record Table, but every time I call the method it returns `BadRequestException: Unknown error at buildRestApiServiceError`.

Schema:

```
type Phone
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }, { allow: custom, operations: [read] }]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: AWSJSON!
  rating: Float
}
```

AWS Lambda:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
  const {
    authorizationToken,
    requestContext: { queryString },
  } = event;

  try {
    const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({});
    const cognitoInput = {
      AccessToken: authorizationToken,
    };

    const cognitoCommand = new GetUserCommand(cognitoInput);
    const user = await cognitoClient.send(cognitoCommand);

    const dynamoClient = new DynamoDBClient({});
    const dynamoInput = {
      Key: {
        id: {
          S: user.Username,
        },
      },
      TableName: "RecordTable",
    };

    const dynamoCommand = new GetItemCommand(dynamoInput);
    const response = await dynamoClient.send(dynamoCommand);

    let isPurchased = false;

    for (let index = 0; index < purchasedPhones.length; index++) {
      const phoneID = purchasedPhones[index];

      if (queryString.includes(phoneID)) {
         isPurchased = true;
         break;
       }
     }

    return {
      isAuthorized: isPurchased,
      resolverContext: {
        userid: userId,
        info: user,
        more_info: response,
      },
      ttlOverride: 300,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

GraphQL method:

```
 const phone = await client.graphql<GraphQLQuery<GetPhoneQuery>>({
        query: getPhone,
        authMode: "lambda",
        authToken: "xxxxxxx...xxx",
        variables: {
          id,
        },
      });
```

Function Overview:

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "{\"createdOn\":\"Windows\",\"createdBy\":\"Amplify\",\"createdWith\":\"12.10.1\",\"stackType\":\"function-Lambda\",\"metadata\":{}}",
  "Parameters": {
    "CloudWatchRule": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "NONE",
      "Description": " Schedule Expression"
    },
    "deploymentBucketName": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "env": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "s3Key": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Conditions": {
    "ShouldNotCreateEnvResources": {
      "Fn::Equals": [
        {
          "Ref": "env"
        },
        "NONE"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "LambdaFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:asset:path": "./src",
        "aws:asset:property": "Code"
      },
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Ref": "deploymentBucketName"
          },
          "S3Key": {
            "Ref": "s3Key"
          }
        },
        "Handler": "index.handler",
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::If": [
            "ShouldNotCreateEnvResources",
            "graphQlLambdaAuthorizer364c8848",
            {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                  "graphQlLambdaAuthorizer364c8848",
                  "-",
                  {
                    "Ref": "env"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            "ENV": {
              "Ref": "env"
            },
            "REGION": {
              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            }
          }
        },
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "LambdaExecutionRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Runtime": "nodejs18.x",
        "Layers": [],
        "Timeout": 25
      }
    },
    "LambdaExecutionRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": {
          "Fn::If": [
            "ShouldNotCreateEnvResources",
            "testLambdaRoleb7fb041f",
            {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                  "testLambdaRoleb7fb041f",
                  "-",
                  {
                    "Ref": "env"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "lambdaexecutionpolicy": {
      "DependsOn": [
        "LambdaExecutionRole"
      ],
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "lambda-execution-policy",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "LambdaExecutionRole"
          }
        ],
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "*",
              "Resource": "*"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "PermissionForAppSyncToInvokeLambda": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {
        "FunctionName": {
          "Ref": "LambdaFunction"
        },
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "Principal": "appsync.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "Name": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "LambdaFunction"
      }
    },
    "Arn": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "LambdaFunction",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    },
    "Region": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
      }
    },
    "LambdaExecutionRole": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "LambdaExecutionRole"
      }
    },
    "LambdaExecutionRoleArn": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "LambdaExecutionRole",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have been missing some points. It looks like your trying to implement authorisation logic for a phone model using AWS AppSync and AWS Lambda.

Check the IAM roles and permissions

verify the authorisation token

Debugging and DynamoDB interaction

Error hadndling

GraphQL query execution

i hope this helps ;)

Comment: It turns out I was providing the wrong token. Adding the correct doesn't return that error anymore, but it does return `BadRequestException: Unknown error\n    at buildRestApiServiceError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api-rest/dist/esm/utils/serviceError.mjs:19:26)\n `

Comment: Okay I will check on this gimme some Time to reach you after solving this. Cheers!!

Comment: This error is indication that there was bad request is made in API. I will give you some tips I hope this will help you.

Comment: Check endpoint configurations, Check request parameters , Inspect server side logs and I hope network debugging will also help this.

Comment: I've deleted and recreated the lambda authorizer with full admin permission. With the initial template it seems to work. But as soon as I add `GetUserCommand` it returns again `Unauthorized`. So I assume it is something to do with the permissions, I updated the Cloudformation template

Answer (score 0):

That error is usually due to the denied fields in the return object for the lambda authoriser. deniedFields is an array that should contain all the fields, mutations and queries you DON'T permit the user to make. In your case, the lambda authoriser authorised the request but did not allow the specific request you made, I assume because you are not returning a deniedFields array - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-lambda-auth/.

Return an empty deniedFields array for example and it will work. The whole point of the deniedFeilds is to give you fine-grained control over what each user can see.

Also, I would review the Cognito API quotas if you will call Cognito APIs in the lambda authoriser especially if you are only caching the response for 5 minutes.

Comment: Are you talking about the new error I'm getting `BadRequestException: Unknown error\n    at buildRestApiServiceError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api-rest/dist/esm/utils/serviceError.mjs:19:26)` or the previous one?

Comment: The previous one. This new error you're describing seems to be an issue with a package or the way you're bundling your lambdas

Comment: I have updated the question with more info about the function. Really struggling to figure out where I'm making the mistake